# How to invert templates dependency?

Tags: c++, templates, std

In case I want to make a generic class template *ResourceManager* which serializes its content calling *serialize* function (or template), how to make call to *serialize* below compilable?

I don't want to declare a function template for vectors, because it is assumed that the project will use ResourceManager with different types of containers and I don't want to declare all possible containers or include this file in the middle of my sources after such declaration.

Can I somehow avoid this declaration or inverse the dependencies so that would work with `std` containers as well as with my types?

In case I worked only with my types, I would make *serialize* their class member, but I want to work with `std` containers, as well without wrapping them.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// With this forward declaration it works for `std::vector`
// template <class T>
// void serialize(std::ofstream& ofs, std::vector<T>& v);

template <class Resource>
struct ResourceManager {
    Resource& resourse;

    ResourceManager(Resource& resourse) : resourse(resourse) {}

    void store() {
        std::ofstream ofs("vector_bin.vec", std::ios::trunc | std::ios::binary);

        serialize(ofs, resourse);
    }
};

template <class T>
void serialize(std::ofstream& ofs, std::vector<T>& v) {
    auto size = v.size();
    ofs.write((const char*)&size, sizeof(size));

    ofs.write((const char*)v.data(), v.size() * sizeof(int));
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 1,2,3 };

    ResourceManager rm(v);

    rm.store();
}
```

Here is the [live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/6xMvhK54e).

Comment: @JaMiT, it uses `std::vector<T>&` as a second argument of the `serialize` and I will have to list all possible containers here: map, unordered_map, etc. I mean, write such forward declarations for all possible containers.

Comment: If it only works for vectors, it is inaccurate to say "it works" without qualification. See my edits to your question for one way to express this situation more clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace `serialize()` function with a trait class, and then partially specialize the trait for each container:

```
template <class Resource>
struct Serializer
{
    static void write(std::ofstream& ofs, Resource& v) = delete;
};

template <class Resource>
struct ResourceManager {
    Resource& resourse;

    ResourceManager(Resource& resourse) : resourse(resourse) {}

    void store() {
        std::ofstream ofs("vector_bin.vec", std::ios::trunc | std::ios::binary);

        Serializer<Resource>::write(ofs, resourse);
    }
};

template <class T>
struct Serializer<std::vector<T>>
{
    static void write(std::ofstream& ofs, std::vector<T>& v) {
        auto size = v.size();
        ofs.write((const char*)&size, sizeof(size));

        ofs.write((const char*)v.data(), v.size() * sizeof(int));
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution. It is very straightforward and exactly addresses my needs. For the moment I see only one drawback, if the type misses the specialization of the `Serializer` this leads to link time errors (like [here](https://godbolt.org/z/qWTT8E77v), but much longer in real code) which are quite hard to understand (they are too verbose and give a little clue on the type which misses the specialization). Is there any way to bring this to compile time or this lead exactly to my code where it must be defined before usage?

Comment: To replace linker error with compiler error, I added `= delete` in non-specialized write(). Hope it helps (but template error messages are always verbose).

Comment: thank you. Worked as a charm! (I marked your answer as useful, but still waiting for answers on comments from *Pepijn Kramer* to make a decision which of answers to accept, since your answer is simple and straightforward (best for simplicity) and his answer doesn't require struct and static methods (potentially best for usability - need his answers). So, I trying to figure out which one would be more useful for future readers).

Answer (score 1):

I would generalize the serialization function like this. Eeven if I think serializing like this is too fragile for practical use. It has too much of a "But it works on my machine" quality level.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <sstream>


// types_t... because vector can accept multiple template arguments (type and allocator)
// template<typename... types_t> typename vector_t, represents std::vector<int,allocator_type>
template <template<typename... types_t> typename vector_t, typename... types_t>
constexpr bool is_vector = std::is_same_v<std::vector<types_t...>,vector_t<types_t...>>;

// Use SFINAE to disable function for anything other than std::vector<int,allocator>
// also generalize to ALL output streams (not only files)
template <template<typename... types_t> typename vector_t, typename... types_t>
auto serialize(std::ostream& os, const vector_t<types_t...>& v) -> std::enable_if_t<is_vector<vector_t,types_t...>,std::ostream&>
{
    auto size = v.size();
    os.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&size), sizeof(size));

    // in your original code you assumed the vector would contain an int only
    auto data_size = v.size() * sizeof(vector_t<types_t...>::value_type);
    os.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(v.data()), data_size);
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> values{1,2,3,4};

    static_assert(is_vector<std::vector, int>);

    std::ostringstream oss;

    // Note that this kind of serialization is VERY VERY fragile
    // it makes assumptions on compiler settings (padding/alignment), endianness of the platform, 
    // architecture of the platform (8/16/32/64 bits). 
    // So in general just use a serialization library! (e.g. flatbuffers or protbuf)
    serialize(oss,values);
   
    

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution. One important point, in my original question I said that "*project will use ResourceManager with different types of containers*", so I mean that I will use maps, unordered_maps, etc. (as I stated in the comment to *JaMiT* under my question) and user types, so I don't want to limit the whole solution with std::vector<>. What would be best way to make it more generic, removing this restriction? I am a little bit confused with `serialize` return type (why not `void`?), so I am in twenty minds about adjusting the code.

Comment: Well other containers are not contiguous in memory so you would need something that would visit each element and serializes it. But as said binary serialization the way you are doing it is too fragile to be of use in commercial products. Just don't do it and use a library.

Comment: First of all, thank you again for you solution and all the comments/warnings in it ; I am pretty aware about all this stuff, but at the moment I need a simple mechanism for cache files creation/usage which will be used on the same PC and in the same conditions and just invalidated, otherwise. I am not ready to use these brilliant, but too complex for my purpose solutions with schemas/proto-buffers. If I were using it for other purposes, I would have used one of these libraries. (to be continued).

Comment: Sorry, but it seems to me that we are not at the same page on the use cases here. My original intention is to have the `serialize` function exactly to be able to write/read any structure, having the code in this function. For example, for `map` it will traverse the map by iterators and write keys/values to streram and read in the same way. So there is no need to have a requirement to have a flat array in memory. What made you think so? I expect to be able to define `serialize` to any of build-in (`std`) and mine types.

Comment: My idea was to get something like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/enjjYcn1P), meaning that we can this way forward declare `serialize` which should work with any container template, but I can't get this code linked, although it compiles. And it won't work with non-template type, as I put in comments in its code. And I see here that it is quite risky (or fragile in your terms), since it doesn't care about types of key/value in `serialize` for map. Is there a way to make it trait-like as in answer from *Eugene*, keeping it a template of function with varargs or so?

Comment: Of course, it does not link, because you cannot have a single prototype for multiple overloaded functions. And if you do not overload, you need to specialize. Partial specialization requires specializing a class rather than a function.